# Is this a total function, a partial function, or just a total, single-valued relation?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations, partial-functions

Is the following a total function, a partial function or total, single-valued relation?

$h: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, where $h(n) = \Bigg\{0 $ if $n$ is divisible by $2$, $1$ if $n$ is divisible by $3$, $2$ otherwise

My thought is that this is just a total, single-valued relation, since every element in the natural numbers is mapped to one of the three (0, 1 and 2), however, it is not single valued - for example every even number will be mapped to 0, every multiple of three will be mapped to 1 and everything else will be mapped to 2.

Sorry in advance for the poor formatting

Comment: What does $6$ map to?

Comment: Thanks for your enlightening question. 6 maps to both 0 and 1 and therefore this is just a total relation, not a single-valued one.

Comment: The rules are not clear.  Are the tests to be applied sequentially? So we only advance to the second test if the first test fails?   Please write out $f(n)$ for the first dozen $n$ so we know what you mean.

Comment: This was a textbook exercise, my answer for which I wanted clarification of its correctness. This is a relation from $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{0, 1, 2\}$, where an element $a \in \mathbb{N}$ is related to 0 if it is divisible by 2, to 1 if it is divisible by 3, and related to 2 otherwise. The question asked to identify whether this was a total or partial function, or if it wasn't a function at all. On reading JMoravitz answer I quickly realised that the element $6 \in \mathbb{N}$ maps to both 0 and 1, violating the condition of single-valuedness.